# What are the best practices for building a SPA application?

Tags: single-page-application

I have an retirement application to be built using SPA . I am exploring different SPA frameworks. client doesnt want to use Entity framework as its oracle backend.

Can anyone provide me what should I look for ? The best practices.

Comment: No "shopping-card" questions please.

Answer (score 2):

Check SPA Q&A Link
http://www.johnpapa.net/spa-questions/

Sample project available on github [click here](https://github.com/johnpapa/PluralsightSpaJumpStartFinal)

Further Angular.js is complete framework you can check that too.

Answer (score 2):

If you can spend money for the course, this is link having vast idea of MVC SPA by JohnPapa

http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/single-page-apps-jumpstart

Answer (score 1):

Front end shouldn't depend on any back end decisions. You can choose the framework based on your needs. I prefer Durandal and Angular (choose one or the other). There are also Ember, Backbone, Batman, and others. There is not "best". You have to choose what works best fo ryou and your app.